Splitting world data between multiple threads in C++
I'm currently working on world management system for my multi-threaded game engine in C++. The problem I'm facing right now is synchronizing world data between main and render thread. The current structure of my world management is as follows:
Main thread: World->Object->[position, rotation, material type, etc.]
Render thread: RenderableWorld->RenderableObject->[position, rotation, mesh, material data, etc.]
As you can see all the logic is stored in the main thread and actual data for rendering on render thread. My question is how to properly synchronize data from main thread to render thread when object data is changed and how world management is generally done in the game industry?
My current approach is using std::mutex and std::deque to which I submit requests, that are processed in FIFO order. Note that the GraphicsQueue isn't used just for world management.
Example code:
enum RequestType
{
    REQUEST1,
    REQUEST2
};

struct GraphicsRequest
{
    RequestType type;
};

struct Request1
{
    World *world;
    Request1() { type = REQUEST1 }
};

struct Request2
{
    World *world;
    Kbject *object;
    Request2() { type = REQUEST2 }
};

class GraphicsQueue 
{
public:
    void SubmitRequest(GraphicsRequest &request)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        graphicsQueue.push_back(request);
    }

private:
    void ProcessRequests()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        for (auto &request : graphicsQueue)
        {
            switch(request.type)
            {
                case REQUEST1:
                {
                    //Do something
                    break;
                }
                case REQUEST2:
                {
                    //Do something
                     break;
                }
                default:
                {
                     //Throw error
                     break;
                }
            };
        }
        graphicsQueue.clear();
    }

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::deque graphicsQueue;
};

This code works, but it has many major issues. It uses std::unique_lock, that isn't best for performance (The queue could have multiple requests every frame).
I'm using pointer to objects, that aren't thread safe, but I don't know how to achieve thread saftey without copying the whole object or using std::atomic variables directly in the object.
Implementing new parts of the rendering engine would require modifying the GraphicsQueue code. In current implementation of world management the GraphicsQueue would need to itterate every RenderableObject in the RenderableWorld until it found the right one and then modify it's values. Because I'm using Vulkan for rendering, I need to create apropriate buffers, which takes some time. This is another reason why using std::unique_lock isn't good idea.
To recap, how to properly synchronize world data between main and render thread? How world management is generally done in game industry? And how to properly manage world data so that buffer management is efficient?

I wrote about a triple buffering approach here, which might be useful to you.

What exactly do you mean by atomic swap? As far I'm aware there is no thread safe swap in C++. I like the triple buffered method, but still it doesn't solve the problem with using pointer to World in the request.

I'm not a C++ expert myself, but you can find existing articles / videos / guides about doing atomic swaps in that language, often in the context of lock-free algorithms. CppCon seems to have had several presentations about it.

Thank you, I will look into it.
